# Chromium Edge 91 on a Windows 10 crashes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run a simple script to open up a google page on Chromium Edge using Python.
What I have so far is

```
   Import selenium
   From selenium import webdriver 
   Path= “..../msedgedriver.exe”
   Driver= webdriver.Edge(executable_path=path)
  Driver.get(https://google.com)
```

Got below error:SessionNotCreatedEcception:session not created from tab crashed(Session info:MicrosoftEdge=91.0.864.41)

Tried several things and searched online but no luck yet.Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: check the version of the driver matches, your edge browser or not..

Comment: Yes, the webdriver version matches the browser version.

Comment: Hi, is there any update about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in the code you provide, I fixed them and tested it, and it works well. My Edge Version is 91.0.864.41 (Official build) (64-bit).

Below is my sample code and you can also try:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
path= "D:\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Edge(executable_path=path)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Please note to modify the path to you owns and use the absolute path of the WebDriver.

I think it may just be a code problem that causes the error.
If the problem persists, can you please provide more information? Such as what version of selenium are you using and what operating system are you using?